# Process multiple csv files on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have got three different .csv files which contain the grades for students in three different assignment. I would like to read them with pandas and calculate the average for each student. The template for each file is:

```
Student id, Mark, extra fields, ...
4358975489, 9,  ... ...
2345234523, 10,  ... ...
7634565323, 7,  ... ...
7653563366, 7,  ... ...
...         ...,  ... ...
```

For the second assignment:

```
Student id, Mark, extra fields, ...
4358975489, 6,  ... ...
2345234523, 8,  ... ...
7634565323, 4,  ... ...
7653563366, 5,  ... ...
...         ...,  ... ...
```

Desired output for the two doc for instance:

```
Student id, average, extra fields, ...
4358975489, 7.5,  ... ...
2345234523, 9,  ... ...
7634565323, 5.5,  ... ...
7653563366, 6,  ... ...
...         ...,  ... ...
```

the same for the last doc. I want to read these docs separately and for each student id to average the Mark.

Now, my code for reading one file is the following:

```
i_df1 = pandas.read_csv('first.csv')
i_df2 = pandas.read_csv('second.csv')
i_df3 = pandas.read_csv('third.csv')

print (o_df.keys())
for i, row in i_df1.iterrows():
    pdb.set_trace()
```

How can I process all three files simultaneously and extract the average grade?

Comment: `pd.concat([i_df1, i_df2, i_df3]).groupby('Student id').mean()`.

Comment: Would be great if you can show some sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process all `dfs` together, you can do this:

```
df = df1.append([df2, df3]).groupby('Student id', as_index=False).mean()
```

**OR:**

If you want to do it simultaneously, you can use `list comprehension` with `df.append` and `mean`:

Below is the `list` of your `dfs`:

```
In [1220]: df_list = [i_df1, i_df2, i_df3]
```

You can simultaneously find average of each student in a file and store the output in another `list`:

```
In [1223]: df = [i.groupby('Student_id', as_index=False).mean() for i in df_list]
```

Comment: I want to average the Mark though and not the student id.

Comment: Just to avoid confusions, can you please add some sample dataframes with final expected output. It would really help, otherwise we will keep going back and forth.

Comment: Hey I just did so.

Comment: @JoseRamon Great. My first answer is exactly what you need. Try it with just 2 data frames. Like this `df = df1.append(df2).groupby('Student_id').mean()`

Answer (score 1):

Use pd.concat to concat 3 df:

```
 i_df1 = pandas.read_csv('first.csv')
 i_df2 = pandas.read_csv('second.csv')
 i_df3 = pandas.read_csv('third.csv')

 df = pd.concat([i_df1, i_df2, i_df3])
 df.groupby('Student id').agg({'Mark':'mean'})
```

Comment: I don't think `.agg({'Mark','mean'})` would work. Did you mean `.agg({'Mark':'mean'})`

Comment: df = pd.concat([i_df1, i_df2, i_df3]) returns for df just i_df1

Comment: Still, after the groupby and the averaging, I am getting just the i_df1 result.

Comment: Are u sure? I've already tested it and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the filenames and directly concatenate the dataframes together:

```
fnames = ["first.csv", "second.csv", "third.csv"]
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(fname) for fname in fnames)

df.groupby("Student id")["Mark"].mean()
```

Probably practically irrelevant, but perhaps nice to know anyway: This approach doesn't load the data into your memory twice, but only once.

Answer (score 1):

using the data you gave assuming they get same marks three times

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = [
    [4358975489, 9],
     [2345234523, 10],
    [7634565323, 7]]



data = np.array(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["student", "mark"])
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["student", "mark"])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["student", "mark"])

std_maks = pd.concat([data, data1, data2]).groupby('student')
print(std_maks['mark'].mean())
```